# Barometer and toriclli vaccum

Tags: fluid-statics

What happens when
Reading of barometer when the space over Hg contains gas or vapour does it increase or decrease the height of mercury

Answer (score 1):

The space over the mercury column contains only the very low vapor pressure saturated mercury vapor. When you put a gas or vapor into this space, the space will expand due to the higher gas pressure so that the height of the mercury column will decrease.